# How to retrieve latitude and longitude and show in map with marker notification

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show a map based on state, city, area, latitude and longitude are fetched from database and shown in merker notification.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, I have already answered your question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29920160/1835912

Comment: @ meena what have you done so far??

Comment: @meena if you want some improvements than you can ask there only, no need to ask another questions... and show what you have tried to achieve this functionality??

Comment: which map api are you using ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shows no effort

Answer (score 0):

Latitude
                                        "  name="latitude">
                                    
                                    
                                 
                                    
                                         Longitude
                                              "  name="longitude">
                                    
                                    
                                 
                                    
                                           Back / Cancel" ;
                                    ?>

```
                         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    var addssByGoogle='<?=$fetch['latitude']?>,<?=$fetch['longitude']?>';
                                    var geocoder;
                                    var map;
                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                                    var marker;
                                    function initialize(address,xLocation,yLocation) 
                                    {
                                    codeLatLng(address,xLocation,yLocation) ;
                                    }

                                    function codeLatLng(address,xLocation,yLocation) 
                                    {
                                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(xLocation,yLocation);
                                    var myOptions = {
                                    center: latlng,
                                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                                    }
                                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"), myOptions);
                                    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    if (results[0]) {
                                    if('1.366667'==xLocation && '103.8'==yLocation)
                                    {
                                    map.setZoom(9);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    map.setZoom(12);
                                    }
                                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: latlng, 

                                    map: map,
                                    title: address
                                    }); 
                                    addssByGoogle = results[0].formatted_address;

                                    //infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                                    infowindow.setContent(address);
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                    } else {
                                    //        alert("No results found");
                                    }
                                    } else {
                                    //     alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                                    }
                                    });
                                    }

                                    </script>
                                    <div id="map_canvas1" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    initialize("Latitude: <?=$fetch['latitude']?><br/> Longitude: <?=$fetch['longitude']?>","<?=$fetch['latitude']?>","<?=$fetch['longitude']?>");
                                    </script>
```